# Read n values from keyboard in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have an exam for basic programming soon and all I know is bash because I work with it. In order to pass it, I have to write an application (in any language) that does this:

"Read from the keyboard the values for a company's production (let's say `x`) for a period of `n` days. Please print the lowest value for production (lowest `x`) and the day when it occurred. Also, please calculate the sum of the production for all the days that are multiple of `3` (so where the day has the following form: 3k, where k=1,2,3,...n)."

My question is if this is possible in bash and how exactly do I read `n` values from the keyboard? Is while loop of any help here? If it is not possible in bash, towards what programming language should I focus in order to learn this fast? ( I was thinking about python).

Comment: Check `help read` command in bash. Specifically the `-n` and `-N` options to see if they are what you are looking for.

Comment: Bash is not particularly suitable for this; I don't think this is a good assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following bash solution. Logic is as if you were using Python, or other scripting solution. The `read` will get data from (from standard input, by default keyboard).

```
#! /bin/bash
min_x=
sum_d3=0
read n
for ((i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ )) {
    read x
    if [[ ! "$min_x" ]] || [[ "$x" -lt "$min_x" ]] ; then min_x=$x ; fi
    if (( i%3 == 0 )) ; then sum_d3=$((sum_d3+x)) ; fi
}
echo "MIN PROD=$min_x, SUM(3rd days)=$sum_d3"
```

Comment: thanks, this looks like a suitable solution for me. What ```if [[ ! "$min_x" ]]``` does exactly? Does it check if ```min_x``` is different than the initial value that I specify on line 2?

Comment: @Bogdan yes, it set  min_x to the value of the first item.